# Msg 13536, Level 16, State 1, Line 133 [Batch Start Line 7]

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored-procedure, When I run it I get an error as follows:

> Cannot insert an explicit value into a GENERATED ALWAYS column in
>   table 'CAS2.dbo.Tree'. Use INSERT with a column list to
>   exclude the GENERATED ALWAYS column, or insert a DEFAULT into
>   GENERATED ALWAYS column.

```
USE [Test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_InsertDiagramData]
    @DiagramId varchar(100) ,
    @DiagramName NVARCHAR(200) ,
    @DiagramClass varchar(50),
    @DiagramPosition varchar(100) = NULL,
    @IsReadonly BIT = 0 ,
    @CreatorUserId INT ,
    @Nodes Node READONLY ,
    @NodesDetail Detail READONLY,
    @Links Link READONLY
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION

            IF(@DiagramId IS NOT NULL)
                BEGIN
                 -- Clear old data
                    DELETE  FROM dbo.Links WHERE   DiagramId = @DiagramId;
                    DELETE  FROM dbo.Nodes WHERE   DiagramId = @DiagramId;
                    DELETE  FROM dbo.Diagrams WHERE Id = @DiagramId;
                DELETE  FROM dbo.NodesDetails WHERE DiagramId = @DiagramId;
                  -- Business table
   DELETE FROM dbo.WorkStationToProduct WHERE ExpenseCenterId = @DiagramId
                END 
    ELSE
                SET @DiagramId = NEWID()

    -- Insert into Tree and TreeDetails table

    DECLARE @DetailsId INT
    DECLARE @OutputMaster TABLE (id INT);

    INSERT  INTO dbo.Tree
                    ( Number ,
                      ParentProductId ,
                      Scale ,
                      FinalHumidityPercent ,
                      UnitId ,
                      Setting ,
                      ModifiedDate ,
                      SysStartTime ,
                      SysEndTime ,
                      UserId ,
                      ComputerName ,
                      flag ,
                      ConfirmUserId
                    )
    -- here you will store the bulk inserted id's 
    OUTPUT inserted.Id into @OutputMaster(id)
    SELECT  a.NodeId [Number], f.Value [ParentProductId], h.Value [Scale], 
            g.Value [FinalHumidityPercent],  i.Value [UnitId],
            0 [Setting], dbo.[fnMiladiToShamsi](GetDate()) [ModifiedDate], 
            SYSDATETIME() [SysStartTime] ,SYSDATETIME() [SysEndTime] ,
            @CreatorUserId [UserId], HOST_NAME() [ComputerName], '0' [flag], 
            'NULL' [ConfirmUserId]
    FROM dbo.NodesDetails a 
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails b ON  a.NodeId = b.NodeId AND b.[Key] = 
           'ChildProductId'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails c ON  a.NodeId = c.NodeId AND c.[Key] =                 
           'InUseValue'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails d ON  a.NodeId = d.NodeId AND d.[Key] = 
           'Mammock'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails e ON  a.NodeId = e.NodeId AND e.[Key] = 
           'MaterialTypeId'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails f ON  a.NodeId = f.NodeId AND f.[Key] = 
           'ParentProductId'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails g ON  a.NodeId = g.NodeId AND g.[Key] = 
           'FinalHumidityPercent'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails h ON  a.NodeId = h.NodeId AND h.[Key] = 
           'Scale'
    LEFT JOIN dbo.NodesDetails i ON  a.NodeId = i.NodeId AND i.[Key] = 
           'UnitId'
    WHERE a.DiagramId = @DiagramId 
                AND a.[Key] = 'ParentProductId' 
                AND a.Value IN 
              (SELECT x.Value FROM dbo.NodesDetails x 
               WHERE 
               x.[Key]='ProductId' AND x.DiagramId = @DiagramId)
    ORDER BY a.NodeId;

    SELECT * FROM dbo.Diagrams WHERE Id = @DiagramId

        COMMIT TRANSACTION   
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

        THROW;
    END CATCH;
```

I'm tired of searching the Internet for the above error.  I will be grateful if someone help me.

Comment: The error tells you explicitly what the problem is. At least one of your columns is automatically generated. Do not include it (or them) in the list of inserted columns. If I had to guess which columns you're automatically generating, I'd guess it's the `SysStartTime` and `SysEndTime` columns, but that's purely a guess. You should look at your table definition.

Comment: Oh wow I was wrong. thank you very much.

Comment: I erased SysStartTime and SysEndTime and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem solved when i removed auto generate columns such as `SysStartTime`, `SysEndTime` from insert statement.
This columns generate automatically from DBMS, and no need to an explicit value for insert.